# render php file return template ::/var/www/vhosts/ does not exist

Tags: php, file, templates, render, plesk

I am using Plesk for my project. It works fine when I render a twig file but when I render a php file in my Controller an error occurred:

```
 "The template "::/var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/project/templates/test.php" does not exist."
```

This is my code:

```
$this->render('/var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/project/templates/test.php');
```

Comment: Please check whether you give the correct file path or not inside the render function

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->render('/var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/project/templates/test.php');
```

The above code is wrong in symfony. render function (used in the controller) is used for rendering twig file content. The above code gives the result like that

```
No engine is able to work with the template "/var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/project/templates/test.php"
```

Comment: PHP templates have been deprecated in Symfony 4.3 and they will no longer be supported in Symfony 5.0. Use Twig templates instead.(https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/PHP.html)

Comment: I used the same code on another server (linux) and it works fine, but on the Plesk server, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I added in framework.yaml templating: engines: ['twig', 'php'] So that I can reder a php file as mention in the documentation **https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/PHP.html**